# Music files become unplayable after transferring to SD card

Tags: sd-card, storage, internal-sd, data-transfer

I am currently using Sony Xperia L. After I transfer MP3 files from internal storage to a SD card using the option from settings, the files become corrupted and can not be played. What will be the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: options from which settings

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your card may be defective. I had a similar problem a few weeks ago. Try testing it with h2test2 ( http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/H2testw.shtml). Note that you will have to format the card first (quick format is fine), and it may take an hour or two.